# Postgres externally supplied parameters

Tags: postgresql

I'm reading PostgreSQL 9.6 manual about Partioning.
And it says:

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's WHERE clause contains constants (or **externally supplied parameters**).

What does "externally supplied parameters" means? Is it env vars? Or config/runtime parameters? Or prepared statement parameters?

Comment: I think that refers to prepared statements, e.g.: `where some_column = ?`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i don't sure that this parameters are known on planning stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name is right in the comments, [from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi-spi-execute-with-args.html)

> SPI_execute_with_args executes a command that might include references to externally supplied parameters. The command text refers to a parameter as $n, and the call specifies data types and values for each such symbol. read_only and count have the same interpretation as in SPI_execute.

So you can do

```
SELECT * FROM partition_master WHERE foo = 5;
```

or using prepared statements,

```
SELECT * FROM partition_master WHERE foo = $1;
```

But you can't do...

```
SELECT * FROM whatever AS w
JOIN partition_master AS p
WHERE p.foo = w.bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Evan Carroll answer:

We can demonstrate that constraint exclusions can work with prepared statements with simple `EXPLAIN`.

Take partitioning example from [PostgreSQL 9.6 Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

And try to prepare statement and explain execution:

```sql
PREPARE prepared_st (DATE) AS SELECT count(*) FROM measurement WHERE logdate >= $1;
EXPLAIN EXECUTE prepared_st('2007-01-01');
```

For me, it shows only relevant partitions:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=84.57..84.58 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..79.94 rows=1852 width=0)
        ->  Seq Scan on measurement  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0)
              Filter: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on measurement_y2007m11  (cost=8.93..26.65 rows=617 width=0)
              Recheck Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on measurement_y2007m11_logdate  (cost=0.00..8.78 rows=617 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on measurement_y2007m12  (cost=8.93..26.65 rows=617 width=0)
              Recheck Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on measurement_y2007m12_logdate  (cost=0.00..8.78 rows=617 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on measurement_y2008m01  (cost=8.93..26.65 rows=617 width=0)
              Recheck Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on measurement_y2008m01_logdate  (cost=0.00..8.78 rows=617 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (logdate >= '2007-01-01'::date)
```